# browserify two separate bundles pass variable from second file

Tags: javascript, browserify

```
main.js
level.js
 num3.js
 num4.js
```

main.js looks like below

```
require('./level');
console.log(num3);
```

level.js looks like below

```
var num3 = require('./num3');
var num4 = require('./num4');
```

bundled files

```
browserify --require ./level.js:level.js > bundle-level.js
browserify --exclude level.js main.js > bundle-main.js
```

I'm unable to get `num3`      `//Uncaught ReferenceError: num3 is not defined` variable which required from `./num3` also `num4`, if I change  `var num3 = require('./num3');` to  global variable `window.num3 = require('./num3');` is fine to get values.

Is there a proper way to have variables num3 and num4 passed through?

Comment: What is `require('./level2');`? `level2` does not seem to correspond to a file in your file system snippet. Did you mean `require('./level');`?

Comment: It's not clear from the question which directory (if any) the `num` files are in. And were you wanting to pass `num3` and `num4` to `main` via the `level` require? It's not clear, unfortunately.

Comment: @cartant. yes they are in the same folder. Yes, I'd like to pass num3 and num4 to main via the level require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think there is an issue with the `require` in `main.js`.

If `main.js` has this `require`:

```js
require('./level');
```

Browserify will be including `level.js` in the main bundle. The reason is that the name that follows the `:` in this command:

```
browserify --require ./level.js:level.js > bundle-level.js
```

is the name that's used for the module. And in this command:

```
browserify --exclude level.js main.js > bundle-main.js
```

you are telling Browserify that when it sees `require('level.js')` it should not bundle anything, because the `require` will be resolved at runtime with a between-bundle `require`.

You should use a non-relative name in the `require` (and, if its a normal JavaScript file, leave off the `.js`, too):

```
browserify --require ./level.js:level > bundle-level.js
browserify --exclude level main.js > bundle-main.js
```

Then the `require` in `main.js` should be:

```js
const level = require('level');
```

If you want to export `num3` and `num4`, you can do so in `level.js` like this:

```js
exports.num3 = require('./num3');
exports.num4 = require('./num4');
```

And in `main.js` you would then have:

```js
const level = require('level');
console.log(level.num3);
console.log(level.num4);
```

If you are interested in Node's module resolution mechanism (which Browserify emulates), it's described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together). The `--require` and `--exclude` Browserify options basically subvert that mechanism and instruct Browserify to resolve between bundles at runtime instead.

Also, if you want, you can specify multiple modules for `require`-ing between bundles:

```
browserify \
  --require ./num3.js:num3 \
  --require ./num4.js:num4 \
  --require ./level.js:level > bundle-level.js
```

```
browserify \
  --exclude num3 \
  --exclude num4 \
  --exclude level main.js > bundle-main.js
```

And in `main.js`:

```js
const level = require('level');
const num3 = require('num3');
const num4 = require('num4');
```